# Pass url path as param in web api endpoint

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have this controller with one method which receives two variables. One is the culture, the other is a path.

```
public class WebsiteContentController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Test(string culture, string path)
    {
        var result = DoStuff(culture, path);

        return result;
    }
}
```

Which i call like in this examples:

```
/Api/WebsiteContent/Test?path=/quem-somos/a-marca/&culture=pt
/Api/WebsiteContent/Test?path=/quem-somos/&culture=pt
/Api/WebsiteContent/Test?path=/quem-somos/something/something/&culture=pt
```

What i you like to do, is to create a endpoint to similar to this one:

```
/Api/WebsiteContent/Test/pt/quem-somos/a-marca/
```

Is there any way to call an endpoint with this format?

Answer (score 0):

only like this route can be used for url ".../Api/WebsiteContent/Test/pt/quem-somos/a-marca"

```
[HttpGet("{culture/path1/path2}")]
public HttpResponseMessage Test(string culture, string path1, string path2)
{
  var path="/"+ path1+"/"+path2+"/";
}
```

or maybe like this for the flexible path

```
[HttpGet("{culture/path1?/path2?/path3?/patch4?}")]
public HttpResponseMessage Test(string culture, string path1, string path2
string path3, string path4)
```

if you use old net version add MapMvcAttributeRoutes to RegisterRoutes

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute(“{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}”);
 
    routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
 
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: “Default”,
        url: “api/{controller}/{action}/{id}”,
        defaults: new { controller = “Home”, action = “Index”, id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was thinking on only passing two variables. But maybe i will consider this solution.

Comment: the HttpGet contructor im my code does not accept that string. Im using .net framework 4 and web api. What are you using that allow to pass that string?

Comment: @LucaCosta I updated my answer. pls try again.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the RouteAttribute template.

It would look something like this.

```
[Route("API/V1/{varible1}/{varible2}")]
public async Task<string> APIAsync(string varible1, string varible2)
{
    //do things here
}
```

You can make the route as custom as you want grabbing the variables you need and adding static route works like API/V1 that I have above.